# Cannot ssh to EC2 instance copied across availability zones

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2

I originally created an EC2 instance in US-East and wanted to move it to US-West. I stopped the instance, created an image of the AMI, and then copied it to the US-West availability zone. After launching the instance from this AMI in US-West I'm now unable to SSH into the instance (it keeps asking for the password).

The base image is FreeBSD 10-CURRENT, which by default uses the ec2-user for SSH access. After some experimenting I found that launching a new instance from this image in US-East (the original availability zone) I'm able to SSH, so I'm not certain what the issue is with the US-West instance. I created a new keypair, I'm using the keypair (`ssh ec2-user@IP -i ~/.ssh/key.pem`) and the security group allows SSH on port 22.

Here's the output of `ssh -v`:

```
OpenSSH_6.9p1, LibreSSL 2.1.8
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/lander/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 102: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to ec2-54-213-127-207.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com [54.213.127.207] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/lander/.ssh/key.pem type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/lander/.ssh/key.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.9
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1_hpn13v11 FreeBSD-20140420
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1_hpn13v11 FreeBSD-20140420 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to ec2-54-213-127-207.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:22 as 'ec2-user'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
debug1: kex: client->server chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:TKZStqOUSM3Eh0LLCEXU3k1LXq2qd1FwxNLQ8r7jkfo
debug1: Host 'EC2 PUBLIC DNS' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/lander/.ssh/known_hosts:41
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/lander/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/lander/.ssh/other_key.pem
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/lander/.ssh/key.pem
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After discussing with a friend he suggested that it may still be using the old SSH key, so I gave it a try and sure enough that was the issue. I suppose this is because the system is imaged and the step of adding the new keypair is not done, so the old SSH key remains in the image's `authorized_keys` file.